# CXF - How to declare an attribute required and non-primitive?

Tags: web-services, cxf

I have a web sercice method that recieves an object. One of the attributes is "interval" which is an integer.

I would like to make this atribute required but without providing any default value - I want the user to be required to explicitly set a value.

If I use `int interval` - the attribute is exposed as int and if the user does not explicitly set the attribute, a zero (Java default for primitive int) will be sent.

If I use `Integer interval` - the attribute is exposed as Integer and is declared optional in the WSDL so the user can't see it is required before sending the request.

If I use `Integer interval` with `@XmlElement(required = true)` or `@XmlElement(nillable = false)` - the attribute is exposed as int.

The attribute can have any integer - negative, zero and positive so I can't use a default value to indicate that the attribute was not explicitly set.

I can use `BigInteger interval` with `@XmlElement(required = true)` but than we are missing the advantages of using the core type Integer.

I would like to expose the attribute as Integer so I will get null if the user did not set the attribute and at the same time I would like the WSDL to expose that the attribute is required so users will know it is required simply by looking at the WSDL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `@XmlElement(required = true)` the WSDL was correct but the problem was that when using org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava tool on my WSDL the client was generated 
with `int interval` instead of `Integer interval`.

The solution is to pass the "-b" option to the wsdl2java tool with a path to a jaxb bindings file that maps xsd:int to `java.lang.Integer`:

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           jaxb:version="2.0">
  <jaxb:globalBindings>
    <jaxb:javaType name="java.lang.Integer"
                   xmlType="xsd:int" />
  </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Using `@XmlElement(required = true)` and the "-b " option, kept the element required (minOccurs="1") and exposed it as an Integer to the Java client.

More info: http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/How-to-declare-an-attribute-required-and-non-primitive-td4815370.html